# Datatables page.dt only triggered by previous next

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with pagination.

In my table I have tags with tooltips which I have to initiate every datatable page load. I added a listener for the page change event, but the strange thing is that this is only triggered when I press previous or next, not on the 1,2,3 ... buttons. The pagination itself works on all buttons though.

```
  $('#example').on('page.dt', function () {
      $('.tag').tooltip();
      var info = oTable.page.info();
      console.log('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happened to me when using datatables with **bootstrap datatables**

Bind click event on the list of pagination elements like this:

```
$('#example').datatable();

//original id plus _paginate
$('#example_paginate').click(function () {
      $('.tag').tooltip();
      var info = oTable.page.info();
      console.log('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to handle a similar situation by using the draw.dt event rather than the page.dt event.  For the purpose of this question I also tested it using the bootstrap 3 tooltip() component:

```
$('#example').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    $('.tag').tooltip();
}).DataTable();
```